Karate Ui Robot - handling of spinner using retry fails
We are using Karate robot for automating wpf based windows application.
In multiple places there is need to wait until spinner disappears.
Tried with function & retry however it just checks once & script moves.
Tried to handle spinner using function & retry variants as -

def isSpinner = function
() { return !exists(‘#spinnerAutomationId’) }

retry(5,10000).waitUntil(isSpinner)


With above code it just checks once if spinner is on screen & does not retry for 5 times at the interval of 10sec .
Anything is missing here?

personally I feel this question is impossible to answer without access to the app and the html, lets see if someone else can help, all the best
